# SystemVerilog: derive input width from parameter

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl

I have an input whose width I want to determine at elaboration time. Instead of feeding two parameters I want to determine the width derived from a single parameter. Something like this:

```
module my_module #(
  COUNT = 9
) (
  [bitwidth(COUNT)-1:0] index
);
```

I have a function which works for me if I declare a reg internal to my module *but* I need this to be driven externally via the port map.

```
function integer bitwidth;
  input integer n;
  integer exp2, width;
begin
  width=1;
  for (exp2=1; exp2<<1 <= n; exp2=exp2<<1)
    width=width+1;
  bitwidth = width;
end
endfunction

reg [bitwidth(COUNT)-1:0] this_works = COUNT;
```

How do I accomplish this? Can I utilize an interface (+modports) to get me what I want?

Comment: Are you thinking of [`$bits` or `$size`](http://www.asic-world.com/systemverilog/system_task_function3.html)?

Comment: `$bits` would be appropriate but when I replace `bitwidth` ModelSim tells me "Range must be bounded by constant expressions".

Comment: `$clog2` does it. Not sure why it doesn't like `$bits`.

Answer (score 0):

It would really help to show a complete self contained example. The following worked for me

```
module my_module #(
  COUNT = 9
) (
  [bitwidth(COUNT)-1:0] index
);
function integer bitwidth;
  input integer n;
  integer exp2, width;
begin
  width=1;
  for (exp2=1; exp2<<1 <= n; exp2=exp2<<1)
    width=width+1;
  bitwidth = width;
end
endfunction
   initial $displayb(index);
endmodule
module top;
   my_module #(10) mm();
endmodule
```

A couple of comments about this code if we were to assume that $clog2 didn't exist.

- Never rely on implicit port directions and types, be explicit for
  clarity and show intent.
- Use ANSI style argument lists.
- Use `int` instead of `integer`.

`module my_module #(
          COUNT = 9
        ) (
          input wire [bitwidth(COUNT)-1:0] index
        );
        function integer bitwidth(input int n);
          int width;
          width=1;
          for (int exp2=1; exp2<<1 <= n; exp2=exp2<<1)
            width=width+1;
          bitwidth = width;
        endfunction
           initial $displayb(index);
        endmodule
        module top;
           my_module #(10) mm();
        endmodule`